# How to determine when and why Windows Network Discovery was enabled?

Tags: windows, networking

I have a Windows 7 Professional workstation that was configured with the Network Discovery off.  It is on a Work network according to the Network and Sharing Center.

Recently (last two weeks), I noticed that port 5357 was listening, which Google says may be attributed to Network Discovery.  The PID for the process that has 5357 is very low (4), and the tasklist says it is the System.

I don't remember manually enabling Network Discovery, although I'm not ruling this out.

Here are some additional facts:

- I have not personally installed any client software that would use the network infrastructure to this machine AFAIK.
- The UPnP Device Host service is not running.
- There is an enabled Inbound firewall rule for 'Network Discovery (WSD Events-In)' in group 'Network Discovery' that is enabled for port 5357.  The profile for this rule is 'Private'.

Is there some way to tell when Network Discovery was enabled?  Perhaps something in the Windows Event Log?

Is there some way to tell why Network Discovery was enabled? Should I look at a Group Policy setting?

Comment: What type of network is it according to windows in the network and sharing center (Public, Home, Work)?

Comment: Also have you installed any client software that uses network infrastructure (like clients that use port forwarding or UPNP, or that display the contents of homegroup or SMB shares)? they could enable and start the service.

Comment: @DarthAndroid it is a Work network

Answer (score 2):

Per [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/choosing-network-location#1TC=windows-7) the **Work** network location type enables network discovery services.

> Choose Work network for small office or other workplace networks.
>   Network discovery, which allows you to see other computers and devices
>   on a network and allows other network users to see your computer, is
>   on by default, but you can't create or join a homegroup. For more
>   information, see [What is network discovery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/what-is-network-discovery)?

Comment: thank you for the info.  At some point in time previous to two weeks ago, the port 5357 was not listening.  Is there some Windows Event I can look for that would tell me when the Work network type was applied?

Comment: well, I wouldn't be suprised if it was GPO related, so I'd disable the service, and then run `gpupdate /FORCE` and reboot if prompted. is the service now enabled? it may not be the network location, but that your sa's have set a GP for services that enabled and started it. Either way, if it behaves that way, you know its GPOs.

Comment: in the 'Network and Sharing Center' > 'Advanced sharing settings', I set the Network discovery option to 'Turn off network discovery'.  Then I ran gpupdate /force from Powershell as an administrator.  Finally I rebooted (I was not prompted).  After reboot, I checked the 'Network and Sharing Center' > 'Advanced sharing settings', and the Network discovery option was still off.

Comment: one other question: which service should I disable?  The tasklist shows that System has control of the port in question?

Comment: hmmm, I was expecting it to be in services.msc, but I'm not seeing one that starts listening on 5357. this is a listening port we're talking about right?

Comment: Yes, port 5357 is listening.  tasklist says it was opened by 'System'